# After updating cocopods using sudo gem install cocoapods, it still shows old version

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When I run command "sudo gem install cocoapods". It gives me success message

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.9.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.9.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But, after that when I am checking the version of cocoapods using "pod --version", it returns 1.8.4.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: `which pod` might help you find the issue ...

Answer (score 3):

Finally, it works when I try sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods. :-)

Comment: Didn't helped, still showing old version